# SPWeb.GetList issue on SPContext.Current.Web

Tags: spweb, spcontext

When I call `SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.GetList(someListUrl)` I get a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`, but when I call the same method from a new SPWeb instance, it runs fine - why?

```
// this throws COMException...
var list = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.GetList(someListUrl);

// this works...
using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID)) {
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb()) {
        var list = web.GetList(someListUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: In what context (control, httpmodule, timerjob, receiver, etc) did you run this code?

Comment: @Andrew in the Page Load event of a publishing page.

Answer (score 1):

`var list = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.GetList(someListUrl);`

The server-relative URL to the root folder of a list, such as **/sites/sitecollection/subsite/Lists/TestList**

also working fine with document library

**/sites/sitecollection/subsite/DocumentLibrary**

i checked for list as well as library.
it's working fine... :D

plz [refer this link which helps you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx)

Comment: Well, the list URL works fine in the second example, so there's nothing wrong with the URL, and I've checked - it is server-relative. Could you run the same test but with the URL to a Document Library, e.g. /sites/sc/sub/Documents

Comment: updated my answer...